# Add another OS to list at start

Tags: linux, bootloader, lilo

I have installed Windows, Fedora and Slackware on my laptop ( lilo is on mbr, and grub for Fedora is installed on first sector on sda6). How to add sda6 to show on beginning when I turn on computer, so I can enter in Fedora (like file menu.list on Debian) ?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know anyone still used lilo...

Comment: It is default with slack

Comment: @Ignacio: Grub2 is still relatively recent, and before that Lilo could boot from LVM, but not Grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to `/etc/lilo.conf`:

```
other=/dev/sda6
    label=Fedora
```

Then run `lilo`.

Alternatively, put Slackware's Lilo on its partition, Fedora's Grub in the MBR, and edit Fedora's Grub configuration (either `/boot/grub/menu.lst` if it's Grub1, or `/etc/default/grub` if it's Grub2 and sufficiently like Debian, and in any case run `update-grub` afterwards).

Comment: Or `/boot/grub/grub.conf` if it's Fedora.

Comment: @Ignacio: is `/boot/grub/grub.conf` the pendant of `/boot/grub/menu.lst` (Grub1), `/etc/default/grub` (Grub2, configuration file for `update-grub` which updates `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`), or `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (file read by Grub2)? Please feel free to edit my answer to translate any Debianism into Fedoraish.

Comment: It's a Fedoraism. They patch Grub Legacy to use that filename instead.

Comment: I done that but there is when I run lilo Warning: LBA32 addressing assumed
Fatal: Partition entry not found. When I restart nothing changed .

Comment: @Damir: Strange. Please post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and the current contents of `/etc/lilo.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/lilo.conf in slackware

then run

`/sbin/lilo`

my advise is to install fedora's grub in MBR and it will manage slackware and Windows

Comment: Command is: /sbin/lilo